# Multiple chain effects with sox Python wrapper

Tags: python, audio, sox

I was using sox to remove silences with the following command:

```
sox input.wav output.wav silence 1 0.1 0.5% 1 0.1 0.5% : restart
```

Now, I need to run the same command with [sox Python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/sox/) specifically.
I have seen `silence()` is available in [sox.Transformers](https://pysox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#sox.transform.Transformer.silence)

But I am not sure if the `restart` functionality, which will move back to the first effects chain, was implemented in this wrapper.